# Warning: Illegal offset type PHP Error

Tags: php

I'm getting an offset error on lines 9 and 19 `),` and `);` but I'm not sure why. I don't think I'm calling an object on my array, seeing as $i and $j are both numbers. This is all meant to display the images in a table btw. Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
            $hero = Array (
            [0] => Array 
                (
                    array("Superman", "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/SupermanRoss.png' alt='Superman' title='Superman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
                    array("Batman", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/d9fa/i/2017/079/7/d/batman___transparent_by_asthonx1-db2yliv.png' alt='Batman' title='Batman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
                    array("Flash", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Flash-Transparent-PNG.png' alt='Flash' title='Flash' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
                    array("Aquaman", "<img src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/deathbattle/images/8/8f/Aquaman_transparent_by_asthonx1-dakip9a.png/revision/latest?cb=20170702181517' alt='Aquaman' title='Aquaman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
                    array("Green Lantern", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/d594/f/2017/197/4/d/green_lantern_request___transparent_background_by_camo_flauge-dbgi25l.png' alt='Green Lantern' title='Green Lantern' style='height:150px;'>", 1)
                ), //error here
            [1] => Array 
                (
                    array("Wolverine", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/4580/f/2016/274/1/f/wolverine___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajhanh.png' alt='Wolverine' title='Wolverine' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
                    array("Ironman", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Iron-Man-PNG-File.png' alt='Ironman' title='Ironman' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
                    array("Ant Man", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/7ec8/f/2016/092/d/f/ant_man_by_cptcommunist-d9xiez4.png' alt='Ant man' title='Ant man' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
                    array("Thor", "<img src='http://www.freepngimg.com/download/thor/3-2-thor-transparent.png' alt='Thor' title='Thor' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
                    array("Hulk", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/f71e/i/2016/274/7/8/hulk___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajha0a.png' alt='Hulk' title='Hulk' style='height:150px;'>", 2)
                )

            ); //error here

        if ($_POST['battle']){
            $n1 = rand(0,5);
            $n2 = rand(6,9);
            echo $n1 , $n2;
            for($i=0;$i<count($hero);$i++) {
                echo('<tr>');
                for($j=0;$j<count($hero[$i]);$j++) {
                    echo('<td>' . $hero[$i][$j][1] . '</td>');
                } 
                echo('</tr>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: exact error, what line id it refering to?

Comment: lines 9 and 19 `),` and `);`

Comment: that matches multiple lines. hard  is it to  just mark the code

Comment: sorry, i commented where the errors are

Comment: should of spotted it before, your array structure is wrong, looks like you just copied the output from print_r, remove `[0] =>` and the ohte one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of [0]=>array(...)  is attempting to define an array as a key. Keys can be Alphanumeric as in an associative array or numerically indexed array.

So you can let the array decide the numeric indexing as yours starts from 0.

```
$hero = array(
    array
    (
        array("Superman", "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/SupermanRoss.png' alt='Superman' title='Superman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Batman", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/d9fa/i/2017/079/7/d/batman___transparent_by_asthonx1-db2yliv.png' alt='Batman' title='Batman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Flash", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Flash-Transparent-PNG.png' alt='Flash' title='Flash' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Aquaman", "<img src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/deathbattle/images/8/8f/Aquaman_transparent_by_asthonx1-dakip9a.png/revision/latest?cb=20170702181517' alt='Aquaman' title='Aquaman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Green Lantern", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/d594/f/2017/197/4/d/green_lantern_request___transparent_background_by_camo_flauge-dbgi25l.png' alt='Green Lantern' title='Green Lantern' style='height:150px;'>", 1)
    ),
    array
    (
        array("Wolverine", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/4580/f/2016/274/1/f/wolverine___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajhanh.png' alt='Wolverine' title='Wolverine' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Ironman", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Iron-Man-PNG-File.png' alt='Ironman' title='Ironman' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Ant Man", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/7ec8/f/2016/092/d/f/ant_man_by_cptcommunist-d9xiez4.png' alt='Ant man' title='Ant man' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Thor", "<img src='http://www.freepngimg.com/download/thor/3-2-thor-transparent.png' alt='Thor' title='Thor' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Hulk", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/f71e/i/2016/274/7/8/hulk___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajha0a.png' alt='Hulk' title='Hulk' style='height:150px;'>", 2)
    ),
);
```

Or you could be more explicit in defining the initial outer array indexes ( like an associative array ) and use...

```
$hero = array(
    0 => array
    (
        array("Superman", "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/eb/SupermanRoss.png' alt='Superman' title='Superman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Batman", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/d9fa/i/2017/079/7/d/batman___transparent_by_asthonx1-db2yliv.png' alt='Batman' title='Batman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Flash", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/2/Flash-Transparent-PNG.png' alt='Flash' title='Flash' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Aquaman", "<img src='https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/deathbattle/images/8/8f/Aquaman_transparent_by_asthonx1-dakip9a.png/revision/latest?cb=20170702181517' alt='Aquaman' title='Aquaman' style='height:150px;'>", 1),
        array("Green Lantern", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/d594/f/2017/197/4/d/green_lantern_request___transparent_background_by_camo_flauge-dbgi25l.png' alt='Green Lantern' title='Green Lantern' style='height:150px;'>", 1)
    ),
    1 => array
    (
        array("Wolverine", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/4580/f/2016/274/1/f/wolverine___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajhanh.png' alt='Wolverine' title='Wolverine' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Ironman", "<img src='http://www.pngmart.com/files/3/Iron-Man-PNG-File.png' alt='Ironman' title='Ironman' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Ant Man", "<img src='https://orig00.deviantart.net/7ec8/f/2016/092/d/f/ant_man_by_cptcommunist-d9xiez4.png' alt='Ant man' title='Ant man' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Thor", "<img src='http://www.freepngimg.com/download/thor/3-2-thor-transparent.png' alt='Thor' title='Thor' style='height:150px;'>", 2),
        array("Hulk", "<img src='https://img00.deviantart.net/f71e/i/2016/274/7/8/hulk___transparent_by_asthonx1-dajha0a.png' alt='Hulk' title='Hulk' style='height:150px;'>", 2)
    )

);
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be due to a multitude of things. As you provided no error, I can only analize what you have given.

For 1,
Your $hero is an array with 2 arrays which hold arrays. Make sure you are accessing these correctly.

2,
Make sure $_POST['battle'] is even set. You cant depend on it being set or even being true or false. Always check outside(and inside) input.

3,
The line:
`echo('<td>' . $hero[$i][$j] . '</td>');`
Is wrong. You have the hero array, as the $i and the part of the hero array as $j. However, this does not access any superhero because you don't reference any. The error may be coming from trying to print an array regularly. If you want to print an array `var_dump($array);` wrapped with `<pre>` or `<code>` tags is recommend.

Comment: $_POST['battle'] is a submit button for a form that encases the table, so it is true when clicked and I changed `echo('<td>' . $hero[$i][$j] . '</td>');` to `echo('<td>' . $hero[$i][$j][1] . '</td>');` (the image) but I still get the same error

Comment: Wrong. rtfm: "Make sure you are accessing these correctly" "Make sure you are accessing these correctly."